# Can't ping or access specific website

Tags: networking, dns, ip, ping

I have tried pinging this website: [www.epfl.ch](http://www.epfl.ch) or accessing it in my browser on ubunut but I can't. I know as a fact that the website is running since I can access it from my android phone.

Also if I restart my computer I can ping and access it but after leaving my computer on for a while I have the same problem.

I have tried `dig www.epfl.ch` but it couldn't fetch the IP address.

How should I trouble shoot this ?

Comment: Is it that website only or others as well? It makes no sense being it the only one you have trouble accessing.

Comment: @ChanganAuto That is the only one. I can access all google services, stack exchange websites and github.